# Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Применение регуляторов расхода позволяет минимизировать избыточную (непроизводительную) закачку воды в нагнетательные скважины при плановых либо аварийных остановках закачки воды в отдельные нагнетательные скважины либо водоводы КНС с использованием минимально необходимого количества регуляторов расхода и оптимального их размещения на водоводах и устьях высокоприемистых нагнетательных скважин при незначительных затратах на монтаж регуляторов расхода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы предложение читалось, его структуру надо изменить, выделив смысловые части, например:

Применение регуляторов расхода позволяет минимизировать избыточную (непроизводительную) закачку воды в нагнетательные скважины при плановых либо аварийных остановках закачки воды в отдельные нагнетательные скважины (либо водоводы КНС), ЧТО ВОЗМОЖНО ОСУЩЕСТВИТЬ
с использованием минимально необходимого количества регуляторов расхода (при оптимальном их размещении на водоводах и устьях высокоприемистых нагнетательных скважин) и при незначительных затратах на монтаж регуляторов расхода.

Союзы ЛИБО  здесь одиночные, поэтому нет запятых (это не повторяющийся союз ЛИБО...ЛИБО).

Comment: Спасибо. Но если все же не менять структуру предложения, то нужны ли запятые?

Comment: Запятые не нужны: это не сложное предложение, нет обособленных членов и нет повторяющихся союзов при однородных членах.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, начнем с того, что предложение совершенно нечитаемо - нить смысла теряется на второй строчке. Разделите его минимум на два более простых, а лучше на три.
Во-вторых, запятая ставится перед "либо" в обоих случаях.